# CSS: Show picture on hover over text within <p>

Tags: html, css, image

I need to create a feature on my website that will show a picture when user hovers a link or some specific text.

I can reproduce this effect with the code below with one issue. This code puts the link/text each time in new paragraph. I would need exactly the same effect but with the link/text normally shown in the same paragraph.

this is the code:

**CSS:**

```
.hover_image a{position:relative;}
.hover_image a span{position:absolute; display:none; z-index:99;}
.hover_image a:hover span{display:block;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>
bla bla bla
<div class="hover_image">
<a href="#"> link text 
<span><img src="http://www.imagingshop.com/images/sharptone/hdr-2.jpg" />
</span>
</a></div>
bla bla bla
</p>
```

**Example live:**
you can see what it gives now: [*test page removed from the web as problem solved*]

The first two links are ok (1st = test via Shadowbox, 2nd with the code below as a separate paragraph) but the third should be in one paragraph with the "loren ipsum" text --> without splitting the existing paragraph as it is now. (so there should be only one paragraph starting with *Quisque turpis* and finishing by *accumsan placerat*).

I suspect it has something to do with the `<span>` tag. If it is the case, what shoul I use instead?

---

**EDIT - it works with the following code (thanks to the community):**

**CSS:**

```
.hover_image {position:relative;}
.hover_image span{position:absolute; display:none; z-index:99;}
.hover_image:hover span{display:block;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>
bla bla bla
<a href="#" class="hover_image"> link text 
<span><img src="http://www.imagingshop.com/images/sharptone/hdr-2.jpg" /></span>
</a>
bla bla bla
</p>
```

Comment: You're link doesn't work.  I'm getting an Access Denied.

Comment: Sorry, as a "test page" it was private and I forget to make it public. It should be available now. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: I dont see `p` tags in your code conflicting with your title

Comment: @DataSmarter - still showing access denied.

Comment: to Drixson: <p>Quisque turpis... ...accumsan placerat.</p> All that text should remain "one block".

Comment: Apologize, I forgot to run Cron (I didn't realize there would be answers within seconds :-) Now tested and it works. Sorry...

Comment: Block level elements like `<div>` are not valid to be nested inside of `<p>` elements. I got bit by this once -- the browser actually ended up putting a `</p>` before my nested `<div>` tag. According to the W3C HTML validator, this is a kind of implicit closing.

Comment: checkout this basic 1: http://cssdeck.com/labs/anxnrkhr ,

Comment: to Roddy: and do you see any other way (walkaround) to make work what I need?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas please put your answers as an actual answer, not in the comments section.  It makes it hard to find the answer in the future if it's buried in the comments (plus it can't get marked as right if it's in the comments).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Thanks for the hint! It works now. Please write it as an answer so I can flag it as good solution (as mentioned by Femker). Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some fancy textarea to paste the code into?  When I view the page source there is a closing `</p>` tag before the `<div class="hover_image">` so it's actually getting sent in the HTML and isn't being interpreted by the browser on parse.

Here's some actual HTML from the page source:

```
elementum a</p><div class="hover_image"><a href="#">nisi <span><img src="http://www.imagingshop.com/images/sharptone/hdr-2.jpg" alt="image" /></span></a></div><p>. Nam nec inte
```

It has a closing p tag before the .hover_image and an opening p tag after that div closes.

Comment: Indeed, the web is in Drupal and the code is added via the "html" part of TinyMCE 3.5.8 editor... But apparently, it inserts the </p> and <p> tags automatically! It wasn't in the code I pasted in it :-(

Comment: Is there a source viewer as part of TinyMCE that you can see?  You might be able to go in and remove them there (I know I have to do weird things like that with Javascript text editors like TinyMCE).

Comment: Actually I would probably just go ahead and do as Roddy of the Frozen Peas suggested above and not use a `div` within a `p` tag. I think you should be able to do it by added the `hover_image` class to the `a` tag and to change your CSS accordingly and then removing the divs.

Comment: I removed it in the source viever but when I save it, it's there again... pfff... It's probably because of the <div> tag as explained by  Roddy of the Frozen Peas above...

Comment: @Femker: that works perfectly! Thanks a lot. I will put the new code as edit in the question if one day, it can help someone else...